# Select PostgreSQL, выборка без повторов

Tags: sql, postgresql

Допустим имеется вот такая таблица

```
 id |         name         |    date    | id_studio | id_actor | id_seans
----+----------------------+------------+-----------+----------+----------
  1 |  Dark Knight         | 2018-11-20 |         1 |        2 |        1
  1 |  Dark Knight         | 2018-11-20 |         1 |        2 |        2
```

Мне нужно, чтобы остались обе строчки, но не было повторных значений, то есть чтобы выглядело вот так:

```
 id |         name         |    date    | id_studio | id_actor | id_seans
----+----------------------+------------+-----------+----------+----------
  1 |  Dark Knight         | 2018-11-20 |         1 |        2 |        1
    |                      |            |           |          |        2
```

Comment: Подавление повторяющихся значений имеет смысл только при выводе этого на экран (или в файл), а значит и подавлять их должен тот слой ПО, который выводом занимается. Поэтому данная задача проще всего выполняется на клиентском языке занимающимся выводом, а не в БД. Вы конечно можете по каждому полю провести сравнение `case name when lag(name) over(order by id) then NULL else name end`, но это как то громоздко выйдет

Comment: ещё, как вариант, на стороне сервера можно аккумулировать последнее значение в массив/строку/json/xml/что-то ещё...